# How to override psycopg2 tzinfo_factory on cursors

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

So because of [reasons], I'm looking at overriding the tzinfo classes that are set by pyscopg2. I *thought* this would be a simple case of overriding `tzinfo_factory` on the `cursor` class. However, this doesn't seem to work.

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import cursor
from psycopg2.tz import FixedOffsetTimezone

class MyFixedOffsetTimezone(FixedOffsetTimezone):
    pass

class MyCursorFactory(cursor):
    tzinfo_factory = MyFixedOffsetTimezone
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

conn = psycopg2.connect('', cursor_factory=MyCursorFactory)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select now()")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results[0][0].tzinfo)
print(results[0][0].tzinfo.__class__)
```

Will still give you

```
$ python3 example.py 
psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=60, name=None)
<class 'psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone'>
```

Is this a result of my fundamental misunderstanding of how the C implementation's members and the higher level python interact? (or am I being a complete pleb?) versions: `python 3.5.2` tested in psycopg2 `2.6.2` and `2.7.1`

I've trawled through the code, and it does seem to be referencing `tzinfo_factory` on the cursor (psycopg/typecast_datetime.c:typecast_PYDATETIME_cast line 140 @ 2.7.1)

```
tzinfo_factory = ((cursorObject *)curs)->tzinfo_factory;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `cursor_factory=...` and assign `MyFixedOffsetTimezone` to MyCursorFactory:

```
class MyFixedOffsetTimezone(FixedOffsetTimezone):
    pass

class MyCursorFactory(cursor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tzinfo_factory = MyFixedOffsetTimezone

conn = psycopg2.connect('...')
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=MyCursorFactory)
cursor.execute("select now()")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results[0][0].tzinfo)
print(results[0][0].tzinfo.__class__)
```

returns:

```
psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=120, name=None)
<class '__main__.MyFixedOffsetTimezone'>
```

Comment: (I fixed the missing passthrough of the cursor_factory, and then copied another version of the example. I've fixed that in my example as it is not really the issue and was an error in me writing my example.)
This does solve it, but do you know why it solves it? Why does setting the `tzinfo_factory` as a class attribute not work, but setting it as an instance attribute does?

Comment: In the native C module, `cursor.__init__` points to `cursor_init`, which calls `cursor_setup`, which assigns to `self.tzinfo_factory` (the instance attribute), overriding the value inherited from the class.